# Caching unique file types

Tags: google-cloud-cdn

I'm currently using the Google CDN on a load balancer backend.  On my site we have a large number of static files that are a unique file-type (not the standard files cached on the CDN).  Is it possible to cache non-standard files on the CDN?  Probably not, but wanted to check.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you say unique file-types, are you referring to custom MIME types? Have you tried using the FORCE_CACHE_ALL [cache mode](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/using-cache-modes#cache-mode)?